# How to insert foreign key data into database using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I'm new to C# and I was trying to insert foreign key data to database using C# in ASP.NET but I'm not able to add the data to database.

Here is my code:

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        con.Open();

        int overRide = OverRideCheckBox.Checked ? 1 : 0;
        int r = 0;
        decimal r1 = 0;

        string query1 = "INSERT INTO Project_Productivity (ProjectInformationId_FK, PastExperienceInDomain, PastExperienceInTechnology, MultipleTechnologiesOrPlatforms, ClarityOfRequirements, AverageAgeOfApplication, QualityOfApplication, ResourceCapability, UsageOfProductivityTools, InterdependenceWithOtherModules, ComplexityInDatabaseChanges, TestEnvironmentStability, ComplexityOfTesting, BusinessCriticality, IsOverrideCalculation, ProductivityFactor, PermanentRatio, RotationalRatio, OffshoreRatio, Remarks) VALUES ((SELECT ProjectInformationId_PK FROM Project_Information WHERE ProjectInformationId_PK = @ProjectInformationId_FK), @PastExperienceInDomain, @PastExperienceInTechnology, @MultipleTechnologiesOrPlatforms, @ClarityOfRequirements, @AverageAgeOfApplication, @QualityOfApplication, @ResourceCapability, @UsageOfProductivityTools, @InterdependenceWithOtherModules, @ComplexityInDatabaseChanges, @TestEnvironmentStability, @ComplexityOfTesting, @BusinessCriticality, @IsOverrideCalculation, @ProductivityFactor, @PermanentRatio, @RotationalRatio, @OffshoreRatio, @Remarks)";
       
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectInformationId_FK", int.TryParse(ProjectInformationIdtxt.Text, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PastExperienceInDomain", int.TryParse(PastExperienceDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PastExperienceInTechnology", int.TryParse(PastTechnologyDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MultipleTechnologiesOrPlatforms", int.TryParse(MultipleDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClarityOfRequirements", int.TryParse(CompletenessDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AverageAgeOfApplication", int.TryParse(AverageAgeDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QualityOfApplication", int.TryParse(QualityDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResourceCapability", int.TryParse(ResourceDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsageOfProductivityTools", int.TryParse(UsageDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InterdependenceWithOtherModules", int.TryParse(InterdependenceDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComplexityInDatabaseChanges", int.TryParse(ComplexityDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestEnvironmentStability", int.TryParse(TestEnvironmentDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComplexityOfTesting", int.TryParse(ComplexityTestingDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessCriticality", int.TryParse(CriticalityDropDown.SelectedItem.Value, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsOverrideCalculation", overRide);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductivityFactor", decimal.TryParse(ProdFactorTextBox.Text, out r1));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermanentRatio", int.TryParse(PermanentTextBox.Text, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RotationalRatio", int.TryParse(RotationalTextBox.Text, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OffshoreRatio", int.TryParse(OffshoreTextBox.Text, out r));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", RemarksTextBox.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            lblmsg.Text = "Project Productivity - Saved Successfully";
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting this error:

[image: Error]

Can anyone help with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are passing parameters incorrectly. You are passing the result of `TryParse` which is just a `bool`. Instead you need to pass the `out` parameter, or just `int.Parse` and let it throw an exception if it fails

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

what us the purpose of the inline subquery

```
((SELECT ProjectInformationId_PK FROM Project_Information WHERE ProjectInformationId_PK = @ProjectInformationId_FK)
```

I believe it is redundant ,you are assigning the same value to ProjectInformationId_FK again , so you can omit it and user the following

```
values ( @ProjectInformationId_FK, @PastExperienceInDomain, @PastExperienceInTechnology, @MultipleTechnologiesOrPlatforms, @ClarityOfRequirements, @AverageAgeOfApplication, @QualityOfApplication, @ResourceCapability, @UsageOfProductivityTools, @InterdependenceWithOtherModules, @ComplexityInDatabaseChanges, @TestEnvironmentStability, @ComplexityOfTesting, @BusinessCriticality, @IsOverrideCalculation, @ProductivityFactor, @PermanentRatio, @RotationalRatio, @OffshoreRatio, @Remarks)";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its not working i'm still having the same error. Is there any other mistakes in the code?